# generally change JaxB class name mapping

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, generated

I have a fairly big `xsd` from which I generate JaxB classes using the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.maven-jaxb2-plugin`. The element names are all capital letters delimited by underscores like `FOO_BAR_BAZ`. This results in hideous names for the generated classes e.g. `FOOBARBAZ`. Idealy I would like it to be maped to `FooBarBaz`. Extending the definition with `<jxb:class>` Elements isn't an option.

Is there a general way to override how jaxb maps element names to java class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case you could investigate creating a custom XJC plug-in to customize how the Java class names are derived.

- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

Comment: this looks promising. I hoped someone already encountered such a problem and did exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external binding declarations file, an `.xjb` file containing something similar to this:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='FOO_BAR_BAZ']">
    <jxb:class name="FooBarBaz"/>
    <jxb:property name="FooBarBaz"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

But you will have to do that for all the classes to be generated. You may alos have to configure the `bindingDirectory` proprerty of the maven plugin.

Comment: The definition is subject to change so I need a general solution. Also the amount of Elements would make this solution impractical.